# A confusion about SearchBar and Tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

without searching, when I tapped any cell, alert shows correct surname. However, somehow, when I search a name and tapped its cell, alert shows wrong surname. In every case (I mean, I search whatever) alert always shows Quuen surname. I think because of when I search, the result always becomes first index of my tableview.

My codes:

```
import UIKit

struct Human {
    var name = String()
    var surname = String()

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    var members = [Human]()

    var filteredData = [String]()

    var inSearchMode = false

    var names = ["Oliver","Harold","John","Thea","Felicity"]
    var surnames = ["Queen","Finch","Reese","Queen","Smoak"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        for i in 0..<names.count {
            members.append(Human(name: names[i],surname: surnames[i]))
        }



        tableView.delegate = self

        tableView.dataSource = self

        searchBar.delegate = self

        searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if inSearchMode {

            return filteredData.count
        }

        return members.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? DataCell {

            let text: String!

            if inSearchMode {

                text = filteredData[indexPath.row]

            } else {

                text = members[indexPath.row].name
            }

            cell.congigureCell(text: text)

            return cell

        } else {

            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {

            inSearchMode = false

            view.endEditing(true)

            tableView.reloadData()

        } else {

            inSearchMode = true

            filteredData = names.filter { $0.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased()) }

            tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        showAlert(title: "Surname is...", msg: members[indexPath.row].surname)
    }

}

extension UIViewController {

    func showAlert(title: String, msg: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And screenshots are here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7RYY.jpg

Finally, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Your posted code is not use ful to analyze. Try to post more code like how you are filtering results after search etc.,

Comment: I don't think it is related to your issue, but "Queen" appears twice in your surnames array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like below :

Change `filteredData` type to `Human`

```
var filteredData = [Human]()
```

Changed in `cellForRow`, `didSelectRowAt` and `textDidChange`.
Added comment for the changed lines.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? DataCell {
        let text: String!
        if inSearchMode {
            text = filteredData[indexPath.row].name // changed this line only
        } else {   
            text = members[indexPath.row].name
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = text
        return cell   
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        inSearchMode = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        inSearchMode = true
        filteredData = members.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased()) } // changed this line
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if inSearchMode {
        showAlert(title: "Surname is...", msg: filteredData[indexPath.row].surname) // added this line
    } else {
        showAlert(title: "Surname is...", msg: members[indexPath.row].surname)
    }
}
```